# Google index https instead of http

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

I have a wordpress website using free hosting of Open Shift. When I search goole for my website name. I received a result that contain https ssl. But when I click this links google chrome will go to:

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from phamquan.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
This server could not prove that it is phamquan.com; its security certificate is from *.rhcloud.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Because my website doesn't have ssl cerification. How can i disallow google index all links of my website as https. Only allow http links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to prevent Google from indexing the HTTPS version of the site is to stop listening to HTTPS. The main problem here is that your webserver is currently listening to HTTPS requests, although your website is not configured to deliver a valid certificate.

If you can't access the server configuration, another approach [described here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63316/is-there-a-way-to-disallow-crawling-of-only-https-in-robots-txt) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/Od2A3AkMx7Y) is to use the `canonical` link tag to link to the HTTP version of the site as a hint that the correct version is the HTTP and not the HTTPS.